# DNS configure firewall to pass connections

Tags: dns, port, firewall

I'm trying to install this software on my computer. http://remaddersoft.wixsite.com/remadder/download

It says:

"In order to be able to use ReMaDDer software, you must be able to establish connection with ReMaDDer server (matalab.hopto.org, port 5432) which is used for back-end fuzzy match processing. Contact your administrator to configure firewall to pass connections on matalab.hopto.org, port 5432."

How do I let the firewall connect to that software on windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following below steps you can open the specific port on windows 10 -

Open firewall ports in Windows 10
You can manually permit a program to access the internet by opening a firewall port. You will need to know what port it uses and the protocol to make this work.

1. Navigate to Control Panel, System and Security and Windows Firewall.
2. Select Advanced settings and highlight Inbound Rules in the left pane.
3. Right click Inbound Rules and do the same for outbound rules and select New Rule.
4. Add the port you need to open and click Next.
5. Add the protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port number into the next window and click Next.
6. Select Allow the connection in the next window and hit Next.
7. Select the network type as you see fit and click Next.
8. Name the rule something meaningful and click Finish.